# How can I show array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this source to show array

```
foreach ($menu_items as $item=>$value) {
    if($item != 'about-me'){
        echo '<a href="#'.$item.'">'.$item.'</a>';
    }else if($item == 'about-me'){
        echo '<a href="#'.$item.'">about</a>';
    }
```

And this is my array:

```
$menu_items = array( 
            "disabled" => array (
                "contact"   => "Contact",
            ), 
            "enabled" => array (
                "services"  => "Services",
                "process"   => "Process",
                "portfolio" => "My Portfolio",
                "about-me"  => "Abouuuuut",
                "contact"   => "Contact",
            ),
        );
```

Now it shows me (when it is enabled):

- services
- process
- portfolio
- about
- contact

I want to show:

- Services
- Process
- My Portfolio
- about
- Contact

Comment: `echo '<a href="#'.$item.'">'.$value.'</a>';`

Comment: what is wrong with my question?

Comment: probably the fact that 2 minutes reading the PHP docs on foreach and arrays would have told you how to do this

Comment: yes... but it doesnt good for me... problem will be somewhere else... i dont know where...

Comment: If it doesn't do good, what does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
foreach ($menu_items as $item=>$value) {
    if($item != 'about-me'){
        echo '<a href="#'.$item.'">'.$value.'</a>'; //change here
    }else if($item == 'about-me'){
        echo '<a href="#'.$item.'">about</a>';
    }
}
```

You are using `$item`, use the `$value` instead of `$item`.